# Dynamic Link (excel)

Tags: excel, hyperlink, excel-formula

I need to reference external sheet via an index, match, match functionality. The problem is that the external file path is dynamic. I tried to build a search using the indirect function; however, as you all know it only works when the source file is open. I then tried to build using hyperlink function and reference it in my index, match. It is not working. Can someone please help?

```
HYPERLINK("'["&Ref1&"]"&Ref2&"'!"&Ref3)
```

generates result

```
"'[Ref1]Ref2'!Ref3"
```

I think my problem is quotes. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Perhaps try wrapping it in an `INDIRECT` function?